# Coverage Analysis in Verilog - 0&&0?

Tags: code-coverage, verilog

I'm running some tests for a chip via Verilog, and I've run into a little bit of a problem where I am scratching my head a little. I'm testing coverage on the code to make sure all states happen over randomized testing of all parameters, etc.

In evaluating two values of the following type:

```
case(state_vector)

    STATE1:
        ...

    STATE2:
        if(!var1 && var2)
             state_vector = STATE1;
        else
             state_vector = STATE2;

    STATE3:
        ...
```

Now the problem is that in doing coverage analysis the statement after the else statement is never reached, meaning that the if-statement always evaluates to true.

I originally assumed that the values of var1 and var2 were 0 and 1, respectively. Upon double checking before finishing my report I noticed that this assumption was incorrect, as a waveform analysis shows that var1 is always 1 and var2 is always 0 throughout the entire simulation.

Now I will test to make sure the values change the way I want them, but I'm curious as to how in Verilog this may happen. Essentially I am slipping into a state because the if-statement evaluates to true for infinitesimal unit of time.

Any ideas on how to better evaluate this problem? I'd like to check that another function isn't changing my state_vector at the same time I'm trying to check my current state.

Comment: Is this a synchronous design?

Comment: Check to make sure `state_vector` is not being set by another line of code or skipped.

Comment: @Greg In the process of that now. Trying to isolate when the state gets changed. I should have noted that this section of code lies within my STATE2. I'm checking another set of tests as well.

Comment: Possible X problem? Are you sure that var1 and var2 are 'always' 0,1 (time 0, maybe, with this block triggered before var1/2 are initialised?) What's triggering this code? How often?

Comment: @toolic, Yeah I looked into some detailed documentation from Cadence and one method to debug what coverage I am displaying (along with what Greg posted below) is to set pragmas on certain states if I believe the coverage tool is displaying data I don't want or that I think is inaccurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty way is to sprinkle `$display("%t %m got here",$time);` around the code in question and make sure there are labels for the begin-end blocks eg:

```
begin : meaningful_label
  $display("%t %m got here",$time);
  ... code ...
  $display("%t %m got here too",$time);
end
```

If the display statement(s) are called, then `state_vector` is being assigned somewhere else. Otherwise the something something is preventing the code from exciting.

To further debug:

- Not display message:

  - add more display messages to higher levels.
- Displaying messages:

  - Some waveform viewers have active drivers tracing. If your viewer does not have this feature, then add messages around all other assigning statements and watch for time-stamp when the condition should be true.

Comment: Thanks. Definitely quick and dirty. I will use a similar method since the code I am analyzing produces far too much data for me to catch the display message or to pause any operation. 

So I'll use another quick and dirty method of having it email me from the server (via shell commands) to tell me the times it reaches these states. It is fairly nice because I don't have to look for the output.

Comment: @Signus If the messages flooding the screen, you can always add some `$stop();` after some of the `$display` to slow things down a bit. Again, quick and dirty. Sounds look your simulator tool has a feature to help with debug with is always a plus.